# Creating model attributes in Sequelize with no storage

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) as my ORM. I would like to create a model with attributes that have no associated storage (i.e. no corresponding table column).  These attributes may have getters and setters, and may also have validation.

How do I create instance level attributes that will not be stored to disc on `.save()`?

**The Scenario**

I have a LocalLogins model.  My model has a `username`, a `salt`, a salted `password`, and an unsalted `rawPassword`.  Each time a `password` is set, the value is salted and hashed.  The result of the hash becomes the new password.  The original "raw" value is saved to `rawPassword`.

I do not want to store the unsalted `rawPassword`, however it is used for validation whenever `.save()` is called.  This allows the model to require passwords of a certain strength.

**The Attempt**

I tried setting field to `''` which unfortunately had no effect.

```
var LocalLogin = sequelize.define('LocalLogin', {
  username: {
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'username',
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  password: {
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'password',
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  rawPassword: {
    field: '',
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  salt: {
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: function() {
      var buf = crypto.randomBytes(32);
      return buf.toString('hex');
    },
    field: 'salt',
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }
}, {
  getterMethods: {
    password: function() { return undefined; },
    rawPassword: function() { return undefined; },
    salt: function() { return undefined; }
  },
  setterMethods: {
    password: function(val) {
      // Salt and hash the password
      this.setDataValue('rawPassword', val);
      if(typeof val === 'string')
        this.setDataValue('password', hash(val + this.getDataValue('selt')));
    },
    salt: function(val) {
      // Salt cannot be modified
      return null;
    }
  },
  validate: {
    passwordCheck: function() {
      // Has a new password been set?
      if(this.getDataValue('rawPassword') == null)
        return

      // Did they try to set the password as something other than a string?
      if(typeof this.getDataValue('rawPassword') !== 'string')
        throw new Error('Password must be a string');

      // Make sure the password is long enough
      if(this.getDataValue('rawPassword').length < 6)
        throw new Error('Password must be longer than six characters.');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think DataType.VIRTUAL is what you are looking for: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/#virtual

Comment: Looks like it n3on -- post as an answer for the karma!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a DataType.VIRTUAL which does exactly that: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/#virtual